# Haskell - not in scope

Tags: haskell

The below snippets of code are part of an attempt at creating a function **generateUpTo** which generates a list **pAllSorted** which depends on **nmax** and thus **rmax**.

```
nmax = rmax `div` 10

pass = rmax `elem` mot
fail = rmax `notElem` mot

generateUpTo rmax = check rmax
where 
         check pass = pAllSorted
         check fail = error "insert multiple of 10!"
```

However, when attempting to compile, the compiler gives a "Not in scope" error about **rmax** in (what is here) line 1,3 and 4.

(How) can I leave **rmax** undefined until using the **generateUpTo** function?

Comment: To the person who keeps voting down Haskell beginner questions, It would be very helpful if you could you know, leave a comment as to why you're doing this.

Comment: we will out-upvote him! :) more seriously, there has been a lot of abuse to SO of people asking "do my work for me" homework questions, maybe it was a mistake.

Comment: @Phyx Actually I try not to vote newbie questions down, but maybe I can explain downvoter. Much of these questions are what term 'too localized' is for and more generally are not interesting.

Comment: +1 this is actually a fantastic scoping question with a simple solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use `rmax` inside `nmax`, `pass`, and `fail` without passing it as an arguement, you'll need to include it in the `where` block of `generateUpTo`.  Otherwise, it's literally, "not in scope".  Example:

```
generateUpTo rmax = check rmax
    where 
         check pass = pAllSorted
         check fail = error "insert multiple of 10!"
         nmax = rmax `div` 10
         pass = rmax `elem` mot
         fail = rmax `notElem` mot
```

If you want these functions to be used in multiple places, you could just accect rmax as an arguement:

```
nmax rmax = rmax `div` 10
pass rmax = rmax `elem` mot
fail rmax = rmax `notElem` mot
```

Note - it looks like you also have some problems with your definition of `check`... the `pass` and `fail` value there are just arguements of `check`, and not the functions you've defined above.

**Update**

to use nmax (the outside-the-where-block scope version), you'll need to pass the value of rmax to it.  Like so:

```
nmax rmax  -- function application in Haskell is accomplished with a space,
           -- not parens, as in some other languages.
```

Note, however, the name `rmax` in the definition of `nmax` is no longer significant.  These functions are all exactly the same:

```
nmax rmax = rmax `div` 10
nmax a = a `div` 10
nmax x = x `div` 10
```

Likewise, you don't need to call it with a value named `rmax`.

```
nmax rmax
nmax 10    -- this is the same, assuming rmax is 10
nmax foo   -- this is the same, assuming foo has your 'rmax' value.
```

Comment: If **pAllsorted** is defined somewhere else, and **nmax** is used in that definition, will **nmax** still be in scope if i use this method to fix the problem?

Comment: in my second example... yes, that should work outside the `where` block.  To call it you'll need to pass whatever the value of rmax is to it though.  ex: `nmax 10` or `nmax myRmaxVal`

Comment: can you clarify on how to pass the value of rmax to it?

Comment: I've added some update, hopefully clarifying this for you.  If you haven't already, you may want to read an intro to Haskell.  Here's one place to get a good start:  http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: I have already been reading that a bit, but thanks.                pAllSorted is generated by a function that uses a list of **n** values. this list of **n** values is `[1..nmax]`. will this still work when using any of your suggested fixes?

Comment: I'd need to see all of your code to give you an exact answer, but you'd basically need something like `[1..(nmax x)]` where `pAllSorted` is defined something like `pAllSorted x = [1..(nmax x)]`, and is called like this (in your `generateUpTo` function) `pAllSorted rmax`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6309/discussion-between-valentijn-pronk-and-adam-wagner)

Answer (score 4):

Just put the definitions of `nmax`, `pass` and `fail` into the `where` clause of `generateUpTo`, just as you did with `check`.

Answer (score 2):

```
nmax rmax = rmax `div` 10

pass rmax = rmax `elem` mot
fail rmax = rmax `notElem` mot

generateUpTo rmax = check rmax
where 
     check pass = pAllSorted
     check fail = error "insert multiple of 10!"
```

The rmax is a function parameter it is undefined outside of the function in which it is declared.  In this example rmax in the function nmax is completely unrelated to the rmax in generateUpTo.